# Convert mp4 video with joining animation mp4 + audio(wav, mp3) using ffmpeg shell command

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to create .mp4 video by joining  short animation(.mp4) + audio(wav, mp3) using ffmpeg shell command.

I have tried few commands to join mp4 + audio here is my example command which will generate output video.

`./ffmpeg -y -i ./output/preview-2.mp4 -i ./output/audio-file.mp3 -vf "pad=ceil(iw/2)*2:ceil(ih/2)*2" -r 25 -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p ./output/converted-video.mp4`

But I want to play my animation till audio playing. The above FFMPEG command only join my animation(short video .mp4) file with audio and stopped animation playing after duration of short video reached to end (let's say animation file duration is 10seconds and stopped playing after 10 seconds). But my audio is about 3 minutes and I want to re-play the animation video again and again till the audio file duration (3 minutes). Just like a looping effect.

Answer (score 1):

Add `-stream_loop -1` and `-shortest`:

```
./ffmpeg -y -stream_loop -1 -i ./output/preview-2.mp4 -i ./output/audio-file.mp3 -vf "pad=ceil(iw/2)*2:ceil(ih/2)*2" -r 25 -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -shortest ./output/converted-video.mp4
```

Comment: I tried -stream_loop, now the problem is of time taking too much to create video. With 20MB audio input taking more than 5minutes to convert video.

Comment: @Dev-D It's taking longer because your input is longer. Add `-preset` to encode faster. See [FFmpeg Wiki: H.264](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu).

Comment: Thanks for your response and help. I appreciate it but my problem solved by first making the animation file till duration of audio file then simply concat the new animation file and audio file and generate an output video. It took just few seconds to complete even with bigger files. otherwise with -preset also not pretty sure